# How to quickly and efficiently roll out indexing across the entire database

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a database with a few dozen tables, each of which can range from a handful to many dozens of columns, yet almost none of them have any kind of indexing applied. There are hundreds of views, stored procedures, triggers, etc. all referencing these tables. The performance is abismal to say the least.

I would like to find a way to analyze all the tables as quickly and efficiently as possible for which columns are queried the most, that would allow me to implement indexes where it would do the most good.

Many solutions I have seen simply show me which other objects reference Table A or Table B (see sample query), but I need to know *which columns* in Table A or Table B are the most used to base the indexes off of.

```
SELECT 
    referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name, referencing_id, 
    referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
FROM 
    sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('[dbo].[T_WAM_application]', 'OBJECT');
GO
```

The ideal output of a query would be a listing where I see for each referencing object (view, trigger, stored procedure, etc.) the table and a delimited list of that table's columns.

Something like:

```
Referencing Obj TableName   Columns
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
sp_Sample1      Table_A     Column1, Column2, Column6
sp_Sample2      Table_A     Column1, Column2, Column5, Column6, Column7
sp_Sample2      Table_B     Column1, Column4
sp_Sample3      Table_B     Column2
```

This would let me see which columns together are used/referenced together, which would be more accurate in forming effective Indexes.

But I would also be happy just to see a listing of table, column, referencing object:

```
Referencing Obj TableName   Columns
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
sp_Sample1      Table_A     Column1
sp_Sample1      Table_A     Column2
sp_Sample1      Table_A     Column6
sp_Sample2      Table_B     Column1
sp_Sample2      Table_B     Column4
sp_Sample3      Table_B     Column2
```

So at the very least I can create indexes covering the most used columns.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use sp_BlitzIndex from Brent Ozar to see where your most used queries are targeting?

Comment: Use [Database Tuning Advisor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/database-engine-tuning-advisor?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @SMor that is not very good advice. The DTA at best can provide some decent suggestions. But it is also just as likely to suggest indexes that slow things down. It is a useful tool but not something you can trust.